# How do you indicate that the return value of a function should conform to a protocol?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to understand generics and protocols in Swift by implementing the `chain` interator (as in python itertools, and previously implemented for an old version of Swift [in this once-excellent code](https://github.com/abarnert/swift-itertools)).

I have a working implementation:

```
struct Chain<S: SequenceType> : SequenceType, GeneratorType {
    var sequences: [S]
    var generator: S.Generator

    init(sequences: [S]) {
        self.sequences = sequences.reverse()
        generator = self.sequences.removeLast().generate()
    }

    func generate() -> Chain<S> { // *** [1]
        return self
    }

    mutating func next() -> S.Generator.Element? {
        while true {
            let elem = generator.next()

            if elem != nil {
                return elem
            }

            if sequences.isEmpty {
                return nil
            }

            generator = sequences.removeLast().generate()
        }
    }
}

func chain<S: SequenceType>(sequences: S...) -> Chain<S> { // *** [2]
    return Chain(sequences: sequences)
}
```

However, I'm not remotely happy about the type declarations that I've had to use.
The lines in question are indicated above.

In the case of [1], I thought that one of the following would be appropriate:

- `GeneratorType` (error: Protocol 'GeneratorType' can only be used as a generic constraint)
- `GeneratorOf<S.Generator.Element>` (error: not convertible)

I don't see why `Chain<S>` is acceptable but `GeneratorType` is not, when `Chain<S>` implements/inherits from `GeneratorType`?

In the case of [2], I thought that `SequenceType` would be appropriate, but it fails with a similar message to `GeneratorType` above.

---

Why is it not possible to declare that a function returns an object which conforms to a protocol?
In Objective C, this is possible with `id<GeneratorType>`, so it seems like a regression.

Comment: The reason that you can't return a straight protocol is that for all intents and purposes, protocols are generic and unbound.  GeneratorType is a generic protocol that can not live without its associated Element type.  What you need, is the equivalent of say `-> GeneratorType<Int>`.  The compiler is complaining because `GeneratorType` is unbound.  To bind it, you need to declare an alias in the template section, `<S:Sequence, R:GeneratorType where R.Element == S.Generator.Element>`